# R suppressing file creation commands (like dev.copy, write.csv)

Tags: r, file-io, workflow

I have a script in R that is used to create files through commands like `write.csv` and `dev.copy`. Sometimes I want to run the script to compile the data (in order to play with it in R) but don't want the script to create the files. This can be because I don't want to overwrite previous files, because I want to keep files (like `.csv` files) open, or because I don't want to clog up my directory with unnecessary files. I'll call these occasions "draft" mode and the other times "final" mode.

So far my solutions have been to

1. Write such commands like `write.csv(..., file = paste(timestamp, ...))` where `timestamp <- Sys.Date()` or `timestamp <- format(Sys.time(), ...)`, depending on how paranoid about file overwriting I am. (Clogs up directory but can be useful outside of this problem.)
2. Include `setwd("~/Sandbox/")` for drafts. (Can be complex if the script accesses files from a particular directory mid-script.)
3. Redefine the file-writing commands and including a menu to ask me what mode I'm in:

   `Mode <- menu(c("Draft", "Final"), graphics=TRUE)`
   `# ...`
   `my.write.csv <- function(...)if(Mode == 2) write.csv(...)`

But I feel that there might be better ways. What are some other (perhaps better) ways to approach this situation?

Comment: How do you run your script?

Comment: make your script a function, and make 'draft = TRUE' an argument. Put the file creation lines after 'if(!draft)'

Comment: In Rgui for Windows. Clicking 'Run all'. (Does that answer your question?)

Comment: Yes it does. And it makes @tim's suggestion quite appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps better: `write.csv <- function(...) if (Mode==2) utils::write.csv(...)`